# Дженерики. Вчера все работало, а сегодня не хочет.!

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe

Пишу приложение работающее с текстовым файлом. Использую Регулярки для поиска нужной строки, ну и там провожу операции со строкой, потом сохраняю в выходной файл. В процессе поиска строки, веду всякий сбор данных из этих файлов (подсчет, положение и пр.) так вот результаты сбора кладу в Дженерики. Вчера все работало, никаких ошибок, а вот сегодня получаю все время при попытке добавления (.Add)в дженерик, Access violation ...... Что это значит я понимаю, это значит что я обращаюсь к не существующему адресу памяти или уже не существующему. Трассировка привела меня к модулю TListHelper, функции InternalAdd4(const Value): Integer; в окне стека написано что значения для Value, нет! т.е. написано no value.

[image: Вот описание дженериков]
[image: Здесь я их создаю и уничтожаю.]
[image: Здесь пытаюсь использовать и получаю ошибку]
[image: А это последствия трассировки]

Comment: К сажалению не понял как правильно добавить картинки.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Создавайте списки не в `FormaActivate`, а в `FormCreate`. И сдeлайте их членами класса формы.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но вот вопрос как это повлияло, я чето не понял, ну  члены класса формы понятно, но как место создания на это влияет. Или тут что то с временем создания? Еще раз  спасибо.

Comment: @ВладШпаков Подозреваю, что `TransForm.GetDataFromFile` исполняется до `TMainForm.FormActivate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что `TransForm.GetDataFromFile` исполняется до `TMainForm.FormActivate`.

Создавайте списки не в `TMainForm.FormActivate`, а в `TMainForm.FormCreate`. И сдeлайте их членами класса формы.